# how to implement/design this issue in object oriented design

Tags: object-oriented-analysis

its about internet shop program. 
Customer, products, Order, and supplier is involved. 
How to implement that the customer can be a product supplier in the same system ?
How to design it and what is the idea to impelemnt it ?

this is what i have tested but im not sure if i did right.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you are on the right path. The customer entity is different from the supplier entity. As a result, if a user is both a customer and supplier, he will have both a supplierID and CustID. This is shown in your diagram by the relationship with the User entity. However, the Customer entity will need to have a foreign key to link it to the User table. this will likely be UserID. Same for the Supplier entity.

Comment: ok now the quastion is if i want to crete a relationship between Supplier and Order, that the supplier supplies 0..* orders, whats the best way to do that, i mean do i have in this case make a relationship between User-Order and delete the relatione between Customer-Order?

Comment: I will propose that you delete User->Order relationship if it exists. Then you can have 2 relationships : 
Customer -> Order (this will enable you to capture all a customer's orders easily and answer question such as "Who is our biggest customer")
Then Supplier -> Order (This will enable you answer the question such as "Who is our biggest supplier")

Comment: last question, How to be sure that my implementaiton in c# for this diagram is correct, i mean is there any way to be sure that im on the right path

Comment: The best test for implementation is that it works as intended. The major work is this design phase where you determine the logical rules.
In addition, you can let us know more about your implementation when it is done, so we can help as usual